# Objects not showing after collision in tetris like game

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I'm trying to make a simple Tetris like game with Javascript and the html 5 canvas tag. The idea is that two blocks will fall down at a time and you have to match together colours. When you get 4 colours in a row they will disappear and you get some points.

A block will fall as single rectangular object but when it touches the ground it is saved to an array and the block object properties are re-set so it begins the descent again. However my problem is that when the rectangular block collides with a block form the array the block it collided with disappears?

You can look at the source code here: http://jsfiddle.net/cEvbd/7/.

Basically can anybody see why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: If you're going to use jsfiddle, it's best if you take advantage of the individual panels... [like this update to your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEvbd/5/). It's a lot easier to see... although you have a **lot** of code that you're expecting people to trawl through.  **EDIT** - sorry, I may be confusing the issue with my comment... you also need to make sure the javascript is set to run in the head or body, using the dropdown on the left under "Framework"

Comment: BTW: The rotation does not work either...

Comment: @Bergi - it needs to be set to run in the head or body, using the dropdown under "Framework", as per [my link](http://jsfiddle.net/cEvbd/5/)

Comment: Sorry, I put it all in the hmtl box because it wasn't being drawn to the canvas properly, I'm sort of new to jsfiddle. Thanks. Also rotation isn't really rotation its just vertical or horizontal. The game would be too easy if it could turn 360.

Comment: @Bergi - I must be missing something, because the button only work if I select "no wrap (body)" - maybe it's just FireFox. I'm going to bow out, because I'm causing way too much trouble. Forget I said anything... sorry :-(

Comment: Oh, right, the buttons need functions in global scope :-)

Comment: I'm not a javascript expert. So what is that, how do i do it and why do I need t do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with my code. very simply I was actually drawing a white block below each block meaning that you couldn't see the block below.